# Can't see files/dirs within a USB drive, within WSL?

Tags: mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a redirected USB drive from a Windows 11 PC into an RDP Windows 10 guest (*mounted as drive J:*) running WSL; when I view drive J: in Windows Explorer in that guest I  see all of it's files; however, when I do a `ls -lah /mnt/j` within WSL, it sees the drive, but shows as empty.

[image]

Doing:

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
C:\             931G  344G  588G  37% /mnt/c
D:\             299G   43G  256G  15% /mnt/d
E:\              17T   13T  3.5T  80% /mnt/e
F:\             233G  475M  233G   1% /mnt/f
G:\             466G   15G  452G   4% /mnt/g
```

**doesn't** show the `/mnt/j` USB drive. (why not?)

Doing:

```
 ls -lah /mnt
total 24K
drwxr-xr-x 13 root  root  4.0K Dec  5  2022 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root  root  4.0K Mar  8 01:52 ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 scott scott 4.0K Mar  8 17:08 c
drwxrwxrwx  1 scott scott  512 Mar  8 17:08 d
drwxrwxrwx  1 scott scott 4.0K Mar  8 17:08 e
drwxrwxrwx  1 scott scott 4.0K Mar  8 17:08 f
drwxrwxrwx  1 scott scott  512 Mar  8 17:08 g
drwxrwxrwx 13 root  root  4.0K Jan 10  2022 h
drwxrwxrwx  8 root  root  4.0K Dec 30  2020 i
drwxrwxrwx  2 root  root  4.0K Sep 11  2020 j
drwxrwxrwx  5 scott scott 4.0K Nov  9  2020 winshares
drwxrwxrwt  2 root  root    60 Mar  8 01:52 wsl
drwxrwxrwt  8 root  root   320 Mar  8 01:53 wslg
```

**does** show the `/mnt/j` USB drive.

Also, if I try remounting the drive within WSL by doing a `sudo umount /mnt/j` and then a `lsblk`, all I see is:

```
sda    8:0    0 388.5M  1 disk
sdb    8:16   0   256G  0 disk /mnt/wslg/distro
```

so I'm not able to see the USB drive in order to try mounting it again.

I'm assuming that the WSL filesystem is having trouble reading the Windows filesystem but don't really know of a way around this to get it working.

(Reason I don't just mount it directly in that Win10/WSL machine instead of via RDP is because that machine is off premises, so RDP is my only way.)

Anyone know a way to get this going?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure whether this question is better off here or on [Super User](//superuser.com).  Getting access to the SMB `//tsclient` share is likely going to involve some Linux networking experience, but the protocols here are "all Windows".  I can reproduce this, but I don't have an answer (or workaround) yet.

Comment: I agree. I often debate on whether to post questions on here/(some other stack site) or Superuser since there's a lot of overlap. But of the 2 in this case, I just opted for the Linux-based site.
Btw, I plan on voting you you as the new mod over on SO. =)

Answer (score 1):

This won't just be a problem with a USB-drive shared through RDP.  It applies to any drive.

The core problem here is that WSL only creates mounts for physical Windows drives using the Plan 9 filesystem.  The RDP share is a *network* share in Windows, which you can see with a `net use` in PowerShell or CMD.

The problem isn't limited to WSL either.  The share isn't available even when SSH'ing into Windows itself.

There *might* be a way to mount the RDP share using CIFS/SMB, but if so, I couldn't find one.  I tried using the `tsclient` share, but even it wasn't visible in WSL.

The only workaround I can offer you isn't a direct answer to the question as you phrased it, since I don't see a way to do this *"within WSL"*.

However, you should be able to use File Explorer in *Windows* via RDP to access the share and then copy/move the files from the USB share *to* the `\\wsl$\<distro>` or `\\wsl.localhost\<distro>` share.  In recent versions of Windows, these are automatically listed under the "Linux" network in File Explorer.

Comment: Thanks @NotTheDr01ds, always love your answers. Since my OP I also tried installing WSL and Debian on my local PC to test this, and even not via RDP (just local machine) the issue is the same; WSL doesn't see it's stuff. In my case copying the files over won't solve my particular issue. I need to use Linux-specific tools to repair the USB drive in question (I know, kinda weird), and I knew that remote machine had Ubuntu installed in WSL, so wanted to try it, and in the process realized knowing a solution to this issue would help to generally know overall. They need to make Plan 10 asap! lol

Comment: @J.ScottElblein Thanks!  And yes, if you are trying to get access to the disk itself to repair, then that's going to be a completely different path ...  It *might* actually be possible using [USB/IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb), but IIRC you'd need to build a new kernel with the mass storage drivers, because I don't think they are in the WSL2 kernel by default..

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for pointing that USB/IP out; I never knew about it and it sounds exactly right down my alley. I'll look more into it (I only read the first few paragraphs there so far), but if it really does require building a new kernel I'll probably skip it. Probably easier (or at least equal) to fire up an old laptop I have gathering dust, install some flavor of Linux and do it directly. But still gonna look more into that link/app.